OpenSSL/3.3.1: error:0A0000F4:SSL routines::unexpected message
I keep getting this error when I call an API from my domain with CURL:
OpenSSL/3.3.1: error:0A0000F4:SSL routines::unexpected message
if I call the same API with postman it works.
it's driving me nuts
I update open SSL to version 3.3.1
I update curl
I tried with guzzle
I changed the SSL certificate

Not programming or development and thus not in scope for StackOverflow, but: in builds of curl that use OpenSSL (not all do) adding flag -v will show lots of details including the TLS-was-SSL message types sent and received (but warning, the decodes shown are not always appropriate) which should at least help resolve this
